# Ubuntu Software and apt shows that GParted is installed but I cannot find & run it

Tags: 22.04, gparted

The image below shows that GParted is installed but I cannot run it either from terminal or find it in the "Show applications" menu. However I can run `parted` but I would like it with GUI.

I am using 22.04 Ubuntu.

Any idea why I see this inconsistency?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find pieces of an installed package with `dpkg -L package...`, for instance,

```
dpkg -L gparted | grep bin/
```

which gives me

```
/usr/sbin/gparted
```

You may want to check if `sbin` is in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is required to open the GParted Partition Editor as root. Launch GParted from the terminal:

```
pkexec gparted
```

Alternatively, launch GParted from the Show Applications dashboard:

1. Click on the 9-squares grid icon at the bottom of the Dock (bottom left corner of the desktop) to open the Dash.
2. Type `GP` in the search box, and click on the GParted icon to launch the GParted application as shown in the below screenshot.

   [image]
3. A small **Authentication Required** window will pop up. Authentication is required to open the GParted Partition Editor as root.